# Make sure you have defined all the variables needed

Tags: javascript

Getting "Make sure you have defined all the variables needed." in this Code Academy Javascript script.

```
// add a parameter called hourOfDay to the function
var taxiFare = function (milesTraveled, hourOfDay) {
  var baseFare = 2.50;
  var costPerMile = 2.00;
  var nightSurcharge = 0.50; // 8pm to 6am, every night
  var costs = baseFare + (costPerMile * milesTraveled);
  if (hourOfDay > 20 || hourOfDay < 6) 
    costs = costs + nightSurcharge
  end
  return costs
};
```

Comment: I have never seen `if(...) ... end` in JS. I guess `end` is interpreted as variable. *edit:* Yep: *"ReferenceError: end is not defined"*.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is intended, but in javascript code block are delimited by `{` and `}`. It's not like in VB where code block are delimited by `If`, `Then` and `End`.

Comment: You also suddenly stopped using semicolons as well, right as you switched to ruby-like syntax...

Comment: One other thing to note, 20 is 8pm, `> 20` is not including anything at 8pm, which was likely not your intent.

Answer (score 4):

You need to fix the syntax on your `if` statement:

```
if (hourOfDay > 20 || hourOfDay < 6) {
    costs = costs + nightSurcharge;
}
```

Javascript uses braces to identify code blocks.

Comment: When there's a single statement, in this case `costs = costs + nightSurcharge;`
, the curly braces are optional, but it's usually a good idea to add them even then.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reserved word "end" in javascript.  This is why it is asking for you to define the variable.  In javascript if statements should use curly braces to indicate what they contain.